# MACD strategy Indicator in Pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

```
//@version=5
strategy("MACD_strategy", overlay=false)
fastl=12
slowl=26
macdl=9
MACD=ta.ema(close,fastl)-ta.ema(close,slowl)
signal=ta.ema(MACD,macdl)
hist=MACD-signal
TradeTime = input(title="Trade Timings",defval="0930-1500")
SqoffTime = input(title="Squareoff Timings",defval="1515-1530")
Barsinsession(TradeTime) => time(timeframe.period,TradeTime) != 0
Insession = Barsinsession(TradeTime) ? 1 : 0
endofsession = Insession == 0 and Insession[1] == 1  
Sqsession = Barsinsession(SqoffTime) ? 1 : 0
SqTime = Sqsession == 1 and Sqsession[1] ==0
if MACD>0 and close>ta.ema(close,21) and Insession
    strategy.entry("long",strategy.long)
if close<ta.ema(close,21) and Insession or SqTime
    strategy.close("long")
if MACD<0 and close<ta.ema(close,21) and Insession
    strategy.entry("short",strategy.short) 
if close>ta.ema(close,21) and Insession or SqTime
    strategy.close("short")       
plot(hist,title="MACD_hist",style=plot.style_histogram,color=color.black)
plot(MACD, title="MACD_line",color=color.blue)
plot(signal,title="signal_line",color=color.orange)
```

Long Criteria - MACD > 0 , close > EMA 21
Long Exit criteria - Close< EMA 21

Short Criteria - MACD < 0 , close < EMA 21
Short Exit criteria - Close> EMA 21

I want to square off the trade intraday itself . Time Zone is (UTC + 5:30) Trading hrs - 9:15am to 3:30pm . I want to exit the trade max by 3:00pm . Can someone please help how to code in pine script . I tried my self and came out with the following code (however this is not working correct)